# Difference between `import directory.module` and `import module`

Tags: python, import, module

I have a directory structure like this:

```
dir:/
    __init__.py
    module1
    module2
    module3
```

In one of the files, say `module3` to import one `module1`, the following statement is written:

`import dir.module1`

As far as I know, to import a module within the same directory, we can just write:

`import module1`

So, what is the difference between the two approaches? I could not find the first method anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is absolute while the second method is relative. The better way to do this is to use `import .module1`. Make sure to checkout [realpython's article](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)